# Undefined operator '>' for input arguments of type 'msspoly' (optimization software)

Tags: matlab

I know there are many similar questions like the title ask here.
However, I still believe no of these discussions can solve my problem.

I am testing the following software "SPOTless" developed by MIT:
https://github.com/spot-toolbox/spotless
This is a software which transform the polynomial optimization problem to LP or SOCP. And then call the other software "mosek" to solve it.

This example is from the tutorial in:
https://github.com/spot-toolbox/spotless/tree/master/doc (please see the last example)

```
n = 2 ;
d = 4 ;
x = msspoly('x',n ) ;
basis = monomials(x , 0 : d ) ;
p = randn(length(basis))'*basis ;

g = 1 - x'*x ;
prog = spotsosprog ;
prog = prog.withIndeterminate(x) ;
[prog,r] = prog.newFree(1) ;
[prog,f] = prog.newFreePoly(x,monomials(x,0:d-2)) ;
prog = prog.withSOS(r-p-f*g) ;
sol = prog.minimize(r) ;
```

However, when run it, Matlab shows the following error:

[image]

The line 401 and the related part is the following:

```
function [pr,poly,coeff] = newFreePoly(pr,basis,n)
            if nargin < 3, n = 1; end
            if ~isempty(basis) && n > 0  % line 401
                if ~pr.isPolyInIndet(basis)
                    error('Basis must be polynomial in the indeterminates.');
                end
                [pr,coeff] = pr.newFree(length(basis)*n);
                poly = reshape(coeff,n,length(basis))*basis;
            else
                poly = [];
            end
    end
```

$n$ is an integer, so $n > 0$ is valid obviously.

I ask the related professor (not the author of this software); he told me he has not seen this problem before. The problem comes from one .m file in the software.

I am not sure if someone can help me test this software and this example and let me know the result or how to solve this error.

> Note: if you really test this software (easy to install), please also install "**mosek**", which is a famous optimization software.
>
> Note: if you do not want to install "mosek", please cross out the last two lines in the code.

Comment: [`monomials`](https://github.com/spot-toolbox/spotless/blob/master/%40msspoly/monomials.m) returns an "`N-by-1 msspoly`" object array.

Comment: @TroyHaskin Yes. But `monomials` corresponds to `~isempty(basis)`. It does not relate to "n". And since we have two inputs, so "n>0"

Comment: No, `prog.newFreePoly(x,monomials(x,0:d-2))` resolves to `newFreePoly(prog,x,monomials(x,0:d-2))`, so `x` maps to `basis` and `monomials()` to `n`.